# Set system clock in Unix to millisecond precision

Tags: linux

Generally you can set system clock using http://linux.die.net/man/1/date. However, it doesn't supply millisecond precision (it does have nanoseconds, but this isn't working on my system). Is there another way to set system clock, or will I need to write a C program to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ntpd` is to heavy for you, try [OpenNTPD](http://www.openntpd.org). It doesn't claim to be sub-microsecond accurate, but does keep my servers' clocks in sync, below a milisecond's range of drift. It uses sntp, which is also a bit more lightweight.

As others have said, hardware clocks do drift, you can't just set them and be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ntpd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ntpd) which will keep your system accurate by syncing with time servers using [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) (Network Time Protocol).

Comment: Generally a good idea, but not in my case (an embedded system which can only talk to its own server).

Comment: @Alexey Romanov Its own server can be NTP server for the device since same program can act as server and client. This way you could have a stratum 3 device which is very precise.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the embedded system in question doesn't support NTP, you're going to have to implement something a lot like it, or execute your C program pretty frequently, in order to counter the inevitable drift of the two clocks.   Plus, your C program will have to account for its own execution time and the latency of the connection between the two computers (embedded system and server), particularly as sub-microsecond precision is what you need.

It may be quicker for you to find a ntpd instance you can configure between the two systems.   The tools for this are always present in modern real-time operating systems (for some definition of "always").

Comment: 1. Sorry, millisecond (as in title), not microsecond. 2. Yes, I do take latency into account.